# CRM 2011 - find "required attendees" in Advanced Find Appointments

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I took over a CRM 2011 service calendar to manage appointments. Now I would like build a view searching for a selection appointments, that means within a time range and with certain attendees.

So far I select "Appointments" and define the specific time range with "Start Time" "on or after" as the beginning and "End Time" "on or before". Both times I combine it with AND and group all times with OR.

Subsequently I would like to specify the people who attended these appointments as shown within the appointment as "required". But there is no field to filter those. This seems rather awkward because it is possible to select "required attendees" as a column to be displayed in the results.

In short: How can an user find all appointments from the Dynamics CRM 2011 Service Calendar of a time range A-B with the attendees X, Y and Z?

Help is much appreciated!
Thanks

PS: I already tried all kinds of ownership, but it does not work, because the attendees are not the ones creating, modifying or owning the appointments.

Comment: Quick tip: You need to look at the intermediate ActivityPointer/ActivityParty entity because the relationship between Appointment and Attendees is N:M ... this relationship entity contains the "is required attendee" flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fliburts comment did the trick.

Attendees can be found with [image]

Activity party is an item from the "related" search criteria. This contains the field party which includes all users within CRM 2011 and therefore the requiered attendees aswell.